How to disable autofocus of Webcam (Anker PowerConf C200)?
For a Computer Vision project, I need to disable the autofocus of my Anker PowerConf C200 Webcam and ideally want to set the focus manually. There is a Program from Anker (AnkerWork) with which I can disable autofocus, but the settings aren't saved, so next time autofocus is enabled again.
I tried to do it with OpenCV in Python:
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTOFOCUS, 0)
But this sadly doesn't work while other settings like CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS do work.
Anybody has an idea what I could try?

CAP_PROP_AUTOFOCUS works on my old Logitech C920 (on a Windows 10), so I'd say it can work. perhaps Anker's "utility" is messing with the camera continuously, while you try to disable the autofocus. or maybe anker failed to implement that property, or they implemented it as something vendor-specific.

I'd recommend stopping all their programs on your system, including any system services. if that doesn't change the situation, I'd recommend contacting the manufacturer. you might also want to try other camera apps (instead of OpenCV) and see if they are able to affect the autofocus setting: windows camera app, guvcview (linux)..

I see customers having (different) issues with a specific firmware version: https://community.anker.com/t/c200-focusing-issues/96947

@ChristophRackwitz
I removed the Anker Application from my PC and it works now with OpenCV. Thanks :)

I fixed the problem with removing the "AnkerWork" Application from my computer. Now focus can be set with
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTOFOCUS, 0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOCUS, focus_value)


